# Retrieve "Specific People" type sharing link from specific document from SharePoint Online CSOM C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing-link

We have a requirement to retrieve all sharing links from particular document of document library via SharePoint CSOM C#. We are able to get **Anonymous sharing links** and **Organization Sharing links** using below piece of code:

```
var sharingInfo = ObjectSharingInformation.GetObjectSharingInformation(clientContext, listItem, false, true, false, true, true, true, true);                
clientContext.Load(sharingInfo);
clientContext.Load(sharingInfo.SharedWithUsersCollection);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

// Getting Anonymous Edit Link from sharing object  
string anonymousEditLink = sharingInfo.AnonymousEditLink;
Console.WriteLine(anonymousEditLink);

// Getting Anonymous View Link from sharing object  
string anonymousViewLink = sharingInfo.AnonymousViewLink;
Console.WriteLine(anonymousViewLink);


if (sharingInfo != null && sharingInfo.SharingLinks != null)
{
    // Looping all sharing links from ObjectSharingInformation  
    foreach (SharingLinkInfo sharingLinkInfo in sharingInfo.SharingLinks)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharingLinkInfo.Url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("URL: {0}", sharingLinkInfo.Url.ToString());
            }
        }catch(Exception)
        {}
    }
}
```

But with above code, I'm not able to get these **Specific People** type sharing links from the list item via CSOM C# as shown in below image:
[image]
[image]

Please provide me some guidance to get these type of Sharing links using CSOM C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Specific People** type is also known as **Flexible** sharing link.

We can get sharing links related information for documents from **Sharing Links** list. Please see this answer I added here: [How to get Shared by and Shared To properties of Sharing links from a document from SharePoint Online using CSOM C#](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298170/how-to-get-shared-by-and-shared-to-properties-of-sharing-links-from-a-document-f/298356#298356)